# Why is that my java class is not reading the MS Access Database . The Application is running but login function is not working

Tags: java, ms-access-2007, jdbc-odbc

```
billing.java
```

This is the billing class and i have finish coding the system's login, it perfectly running in the Frame but one i input the usernames and password the access database is not detected.

public class billing {

```
    Connection con;
    Statement st;
    ResultSet rs; 

    JFrame f = new JFrame ("User Login");
    JLabel l = new JLabel ("Username:");
    JLabel l1 = new JLabel ("Password:");
    JTextField t = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField t1 = new JTextField(10);
    JButton b = new JButton("Login");


    public billing()
    {
        connect();
        frame();
    }   

    public void connect()
    {

        try{


        String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.Driver";
        Class.forName(driver);

        String db = "jdbc:odbc:dbB";
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(db) ;
        st = con.createStatement();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }

    public void frame()
    {
    f.setSize (600,400);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setVisible(true);

    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.add(l);
    p.add(t);
    p.add(l1);
    p.add(t1);
    p.add(b);

    f.add(p);


    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
        try
            {
        String user = t.getText().trim();
        String pass = t1.getText().trim();

        String sql ="select user,pass from Table2 where username ='"+user+" ' and password =' "+pass+" ' ";  // sql code
        rs = st.executeQuery(sql);


        }

        abstract 
        int count = 0;
        while(rs.next())

        {
        count = count +1;
        } 

        if (count == 1) 
        {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successfully Login");
        }
        else if (count > 1)
        {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Duplicate Account, Access Denied");
        }
        else 
        {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User Not Found");
        }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

     }

    }
});
```

}

```
public static void main (String[] args){

        new billing();
}
```

}

please help ... this is very confusing and i dont know wher did i go wrong..

Comment: Since you don't explain much of WHAT is really happenning, it is hard to tell. That said, I've been told that JdbcOdbc bridge is no longer working on Windows 64 (although you should confirm that on Google).

Comment: Can you post a stack trace?  What is it exactly that's happening here?

Answer (score 0):

You have additional spaces surrounding the username and password fields

```
String sql = "select user,pass from Table2 where username ='" + user + " ' and password =' " + pass + " ' "; // sql
```

Replace with

```
String sql = "select user,pass from Table2 where username ='" + user + "' and password ='" + pass + "'";
```

That said, look at using a `PreparedStatement` to protect against [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks